# My php code returns jibberish

Tags: php

So I'm trying to connect my very basic android application to an apache server.
I went as far as downloading wampserver and have started coding the php files to connect and post (both separate files). While it is connecting to my database, it is failing to retrieve or to post data into the database using php.

```
    <?php

require "init.php";


$name="Lucky";
$message="Getlow";

$sql_query="select * from post_its where name = '$name';";

$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
 echo "Login Successful";
}
else
{
 echo "Error";
}
?>
```

My php file for connecting to the database is given below:

```
    <?php
$db_name="webappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con)
 echo Connection Error;
else
 echo <h3>Connection Success</h3>
?>
```

In my browser when I try and run my post.php file, it shows me:

Connection Success ?>(followed by random chinese characters)

Please help!

Comment: Your echo's should be quoted, ie.`echo  "<h3>Connection Success</h3>"` (unsure if that is related tho)

Comment: The strings need to be quoted ---> if(!$con)
 echo 'Connection Error';
else
 echo '<h3>Connection Success</h3>';